# Kernel module logging using sysfs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c

How can I log my kernel module (let's call him "test") work process to read by typing `cat /sys/module/test/stat/volumes`? Which way should I go? Have I use something from kobject functionality or it's possible to write from kernel functions?

Can you please give examples of such work?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to use kobject approach and create function (of course with all the auxiliary) like this:

```c
static struct kobj_attribute stat_info_attribute = __ATTR(volumes, 0444, stat_info_show, stat_info_store);
```

After that you have to initializate it in __init function.

Full listing with realisation you can find [here](https://github.com/Nik-Poch/device-mapper-proxy/blob/master/dmp/dmp.c).